# Unable to run the Java code in Intellij IDEA : error during Compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public class RotationsNumbers {
    public int main(String[] args) {
        Solution ans= new Solution();
        int[] arr= {5, 1,2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(ans.findKRotation(arr , 5));
        return -1;
    }

    class Solution {
        int findKRotation(int arr[], int n) {
            // code here
            int ans= findPivot(arr, 0 , n-1);
            if( ans ==-1) return 0;
            return ans+1;


        }
        int findPivot( int arr[], int start, int end){
            int mid ;
            while(start< end){
                mid= start+ (end- start)/2;
                if (mid < end && arr[mid]> arr[mid+1]){
                    return mid;
                }
                if ( mid > start && arr[mid ]< arr[mid-1]){
                    return mid-1;

                }
                if ( arr[ mid ] < arr[0]){
                    end= mid-1;
                }else{
                    start= mid+1;
                }

            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : Tried using static void main too .. still throwing error
For the above code below error is getting thrown , what should i do?

Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class BinarySearch.SortedArray, please
define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: well, it says in the error already. You must define the main method as "public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: i did that still throwing error

Comment: You have to remove `return -1` from main function as well

Comment: what it says in the error after you fix that?

Comment: Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class BinarySearch.SortedArray, please 
define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: okay remove return statement as well.

Comment: yes removed : saying should return value of type Void

Comment: can you please edit the code above as how you changed it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some problems that I see

1. like mentioned in the comment the main should be `public static void main`
2. return statement in main need to go

the below code should work

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr= {5, 1,2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(findKRotation(arr , 5));
    }

    static int findKRotation(int arr[], int n) {
        // code here
        int ans= findPivot(arr, 0 , n-1);
        if( ans ==-1) return 0;
        return ans+1;


    }
    static int findPivot( int arr[], int start, int end){
        int mid ;
        while(start< end){
            mid= start+ (end- start)/2;
            if (mid < end && arr[mid]> arr[mid+1]){
                return mid;
            }
            if ( mid > start && arr[mid ]< arr[mid-1]){
                return mid-1;

            }
            if ( arr[ mid ] < arr[0]){
                end= mid-1;
            }else{
                start= mid+1;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `missing constructor for solution` --> no explicit constructor is needed.

Comment: oof my bad will change that

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a reason you went with the class construction that you've gone with so I won't make any changes beyond addressing your question / concern:

> Unable to run the Java code

To run your code make these changes;

**Your Solution:**

```
public int main(String[] args) {
        Solution ans= new Solution();
        int[] arr= {5, 1,2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(ans.findKRotation(arr , 5));
        return -1;
    }
```

**Changed to:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
        Solution ans= new Solution();
        int[] arr= {5, 1,2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(ans.findKRotation(arr , 5));
    }
```

**Your Solution:**

```
class Solution {
```

**Changed to:**

```
static class Solution {
```

With these minimal changes, your code should run.